# IE plugins in system.windows.forms.webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using system.windows.forms.webbrowser in my Win forms application with IE as my default browser. Does the IE plugin/ Patch be applicable for my WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you read the document you will find that `system.windows.forms.webbrowser` is using embedded Internet Explorer regardless of what your default browser is.

AFAIK there is no built in way to use chrome as embedded browser in win form. You need a third party lib for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply Steve. Do you know if i have a plugin in IE, would that be applied to my WebBrowser component too?

Comment: @Praddy depends on your IE's security settings. if its on default then I think it should. You can verify it yourself by opening up the plugin settings